# How to make a facebook video which infact is a game? is it flash or facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, flash, video, canvas

I just saw this [Game](http://www.thegma.com/htc-game/) posted on a [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/HTCPakistanOfficial/)
which is strange for me because it has the play button like a video plus main features i.e share comment, like buttons. Can anybody explain how this is done. My initial R&D suggest its either flash (more likely) or may be facebook Canvas. Plus elaborate how can app like this can be made. Help!

> **Main Screen**

[image]

> **Game Screen**

[image]

> **Game Play Screen**

[image]

Comment: Does it actually play a video when you click on it?  Or does it just take you to another page?  Usually these things are nothing more than a graphic that APPEARS to have a play button to bait you into clicking it.

Comment: yes it does!! that is the strange thing. yes most of the games are like that. but in those cases they are not well embedded in facebook (some ask navigation to a website or a facebook App page). but in this case it is. No navigation no page refresh. @durbnpoisn

Comment: Huh...  That is odd.  Perhaps they have opened something new in Open Graph.  Having said that, I doubt that anyone here could help you...  Other than pointing out that Open Graph is the place to start looking.

Comment: It’s not new, it has existed for ages. At one point, it was even in the documentation, they called it “feed gaming.” And yeah, an SWF flash file embedded using the og:video meta tag is all it is.